# Not able to find Resource id in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not able to find Resource Id of the EditText in this Activity.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Views;

namespace ExpenseApp.Android.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "View for FirstViewModel")]
    public class FirstView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
           EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_user_name);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also clean the solution,and rebuild the solution but still not able to find the solution.

Comment: Doesn't it compile/run? What is the error?

Comment: Do you have a ViewModel for your "FirstView"? Why don't you use your ViewModel for binding a value to your view? That's the intention of MvvmCross.

Comment: I'm  not bale to compile it.Its showing cannot bale to find resource id.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" // add this line
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Value Property" /> <-- bind your data direct

    </LinearLayout>
```

I dont know why this error raised may be you dont need to use `FindViewById` method as you use `MvxActivity` you can bind data by the way I mention

hope this work